# How to stop this text rotator on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, pause, rotator

Can someone help me. I want to add an option to pause on hover. How to do it? I found this script on the Internet.  I don't know anything about programming. I can only implement. I will be grateful for any help. If this is not possible, please give me some suggestions. Where can I download a similar script with random display and pause on mouseover option.

style.css

```
body { text-align:center; background-color:#7F8C8D; color:#fff; margin:0}
#demo { list-style: none; color:#fff; }
#demo li { display: none; }
```

site.htm

```
<ul id="demo">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="1.php">1</a></li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="2.php">2</a></li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="3.php">3</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(function(){
  $('#demo').textRotator({
   random : true,
   fadeIn : 1000,
   fadeOut : 500,
   duration : 5000,
   debug : false
   })
})
</script>
```

script.js

```
(function($) {
    $.textRotator = function(element, options) {
        var defaults = {
            random : false,
            fadeIn : 1000,
            fadeOut : 500,
            duration : 5000, 
            easingin : 'swing',
            easingout : 'swing'
        }
        var plugin = this;
        plugin.settings = {}
        plugin.globals = {
            child_select : 1,
            $child_select : null
        }
        var $element = $(element), element = element;    /* reference to the actual DOM element*/
        // the "constructor" method that gets called when the object is created
        plugin.init = function() {
            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            if (plugin.settings.random){ plugin._shuffle($element.children());  }
            plugin.globals.$child_select = $element.find('li:nth-child('+ plugin.globals.child_select+')');
            plugin._fadeIn();
        }
        //resizes main image
        plugin._fadeIn = function() {           
            plugin.globals.$child_select.fadeIn({
                    duration : plugin.settings.fadeIn,
                    easing: plugin.globals.$child_select.data('easingin') ? plugin.globals.$child_select.data('easingin') : plugin.settings.easingin,
                    complete: function () {
                        if ($element.find('li').length > 1) {plugin._fadeOut(); }                       
                    }               
                });      
        }
        plugin._shuffle = function($el) {
            var allElems = $el.get(),
                getRandom = function(max) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * max); },
                shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
                    var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                        randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
                    allElems.splice(random, 1);
                    return randEl;
               });   
            $el.each(function(i){$(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));});
        }
        
        plugin._fadeOut = function() {
            var sliedDuration = plugin.globals.$child_select.data('duration') ? plugin.globals.$child_select.data('duration') : plugin.settings.duration;
            plugin.globals.$child_select.delay(sliedDuration).fadeOut({
                duration : plugin.settings.fadeOut,
                easing: plugin.globals.$child_select.data('easingout') ? plugin.globals.$child_select.data('easingout') : plugin.settings.easingout,
                complete: function () {
                    if  ((plugin.globals.$child_select.index() + 1) == $element.children().length){
                        console.log('last')
                        plugin.globals.$child_select = $element.children().first();                                                 
                    }
                    else {
                        plugin.globals.$child_select = plugin.globals.$child_select.next('li');                             
                    }
                    plugin._fadeIn();                       
                }               
            });                 
        }
        plugin.init();
    }
    // add the plugin to the jQuery.fn object
    $.fn.textRotator = function(options) {
        // iterate through the DOM elements we are attaching the plugin to
        return this.each(function() {
            // if plugin has not already been attached to the element
            if (undefined == $(this).data('textRotator')) {
                var plugin = new $.textRotator(this, options);
                $(this).data('textRotator', plugin);
            }
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Here is the preview link.

(https://jsfiddle.net/b9jopfta/)